# PHP cURL API response handling

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have a question regarding the handling of a response from an API using the cURL function from PHP.
If I access the API via cURL I get the following response:

```
{"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"data":{"502268596":{"clan_id":500022074}}}
```

I transformed this code (named $json) using:

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode($json,true);
```

If I var_dump the associative array I now got I receive the following:

```
array(3) { ["status"]=> string(2) "ok" ["meta"]=> array(1) { ["count"]=> int(1) } ["data"]=> array(1) { [502268596]=> array(1) { ["clan_id"]=> int(500022074) } } }
```

My Question is: How do I access the field "clan_id"? I'm absolutely lost, because I don't have a real understanding of how arrays work and how I cycle through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response data is in array format. In this specific case, you can access clan id as follows:

```
echo $jsondecoded['data'][502268596]['clan_id'];
```

If you would rather work with objects, you can do so this way:

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode($json);
echo $jsondecoded->data->{502268596}->clan_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for that really quick answer. :)

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it helped you.